# Efficient way of getting contact name and phone number in a List View in android

Tags: android

i want to get contact name and phone number in a list view using cursors and simple cursor adaptor. I have seen codes which loops over all the contacts in the database. Is there an efficient way to do this by merging cursors and using simple cursor adaptor to make a list view?

Comment: Yes it is possible to show contact in ListView. What is your question?

Comment: I want to use Simplecursoradapter to generate a listview containing name and phone number. The idea is not to loop over contacts but directly picking the data using cursors.

Answer (score 0):

You get everything about contacts in this Cursor

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

But the to get the name or id from this cursor you have to loop through there is no other possibility.